# Javascript Locale Date Conversions

Tags: javascript, date, locale

I have a string coming into a function, this string is a date from Sweden and is formatted `2016 maj 01`. Passed into this function is the country code for the locale `sv-se`. I need to convert the date string into a valid date object, to which I can then apply the locale.

This is for global date validation.

SO far I have

```
var date = new Date();
Intl.dateTimeFormat(locale, options).format(date);
```

I want to be able to have `new Date("2016 maj 01")` however since this is not English this is an invalid date. Can I using the locale convert this to a valid date object?

It was suggested my problem is similar to another. The way my problem is different is that I have the month coming in as the months abbreviated name. If the month was displayed numerically this would not be an issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS: new Date() is not accepting date string in my own locale (d/m/y)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165483/js-new-date-is-not-accepting-date-string-in-my-own-locale-d-m-y)

Comment: unfortunately not, my month comes in as an abbreviated string not a numerical value (maj not 5)

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, it's probably a duplicate of an existing question. JavaScript Date object cannot be built from localized string.

However, you wan make your own Date builder from swedish:

```js
Date.fromSwedish = (function() {
  var months = {
    'jan': 0,
    'feb': 1,
    'mar': 2,
    'apr': 3,
    'maj': 4 /*...*/
  };

  return function(s) {
    var splitted = s.split(' ');
    var year = splitted.length > 0 ? splitted[0] : 1970;
    var month = splitted.length > 1 ? months[splitted[1].toLowerCase()] : 0 ;
    var day = splitted.length > 2 ? splitted[2] : 1;
    return new Date(year, month, day);
  };
}());

document.write(Date.fromSwedish("2016") + "<br/>");
document.write(Date.fromSwedish("2016 feb") + "<br/>");
document.write(Date.fromSwedish("2016 maj 01") + "<br/>");
```

Comment: this looks good, problem is I need it for Danish, Finnish and Norwegian as well. I was hoping for a global solution.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to implement your own versions for other languages, or find a globalization library

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do the opposite of the method ***Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()***, which returns formatted string based on the passed Locale and options arguments. You can read more about it  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Now, here you want to do the opposite of what ***toLocaleDateString*** method does, you want to give a formatted date string with a Locale, and you expect it to return a date object. To do so, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936472/opposite-method-to-tolocaledatestring), I hope it can help you to get a head start.

Also, if you are comfortable to use external libraries then you can explore for localization libraries like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: that is helpful, but I still have the issue of my date having a name in it. My date is not purely numeric.